# zend code hinting in a non-zend project?

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework, code-hinting

I'm trying to get code hinting in eclipse for zend in a non-Zend project. The code works fine, but all I'm getting for code hinting is `Zend_5250_`. Is there something I need to do to get those code hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the Zend Framework Library to the Project Resources.

Right Click Project Folder, then Properties, then PHP Include Path, then Tab Libraries, add Zend Framework to it.